# Offering a bounty for a flag

Tags: feature-request, flags

Today I had an idea: making people able to offer a bounty for a flag, just like you can offer bounties for questions. So, you could be able to offer a small amount of rep (5 to 100 for example), to bring your flag at the top of the 'flags' tab in the 10K-tools, or creating a 'featured' tab for flags also. This would be useful for unhandled flags for very offensive questions/answers.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to how the Close-Vote review queue is 94K large.

Comment: If the flag is urgent enough for you to have to put a bounty on it, it will get review soon enough.

Comment: Would the bounty go to the person who handles the flag? If not, it doesn't sound much like a bounty. (And if so, does it go to that person only if the flag is marked helpful, which would make it a "bribe" for accepting flags?)

Comment: This makes sense if you think about it not as a bounty but as "I, a highly-respected member, think this is VERY IMPORTANT, and I'm staking my reputation on that", but I don't really see a need for it. Things that are super-urgent (spam, abusive language) generally get jumped on by regular members quite quickly without a moderator needing to be involved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Offensive and spam flags already get promoted to the very top of the moderator queue.  On Stack Overflow, such flags typically get handled within 20 minutes or so, or immediately if a mod happens to be already working the queue.